# How to set timer in my android code using threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am new to android. 
I am trying to set timer for my code using thread which should increment 1 for each second and set the value to TextView. But Whenever i compile my code, it is showing some exceptions in "thtim" thread.

```
03-11 07:20:41.018: W/dalvikvm(1085): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-11 07:20:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
03-11 07:20:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 07:20:41.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.kbt.testing.TestingActivity$1.run(TestingActivity.java:49)
03-11 07:20:44.023: I/Process(1085): Sending signal. PID: 1085 SIG: 9
03-11 07:20:48.610: W/dalvikvm(1095): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-11 07:20:48.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
03-11 07:20:48.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 07:20:48.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.kbt.testing.TestingActivity$1.run(TestingActivity.java:49)
```

These are errors i am facing... Please help me how to set up a timer and also tell me what mistake i did in my code.. 
Thanks a lot for your help..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestingActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;int time=0;
    ProgressBar pb,pbo;int clicks=0,i=0,j;
    TextView timer;Handler h;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
        pbo = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbo);
        pb.setProgress(0);
        pb.setMax(300);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        pbo.setProgress(0);
        pbo.setMax(300);
        pbo.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);    
        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

    Thread thtim=new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for(j=1;j<30;j++){
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    h.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            timer.setText("Timer :"+j);
                            Log.i("kbt", "inside for new");
                        }
                    });



                    }

        }
    };
    thtim.start();

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clicks++;
            pbo.setProgress(clicks);

        }
    });
    Thread t=new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(i=-5;i<300;i++)
            {
                pb.setProgress(i);
                try {
                    sleep(600);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    };
    t.start();



}
}
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What part of it generates the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not initialized the Handler i.e you are missing the below statement in code:

```
Handler h=new Handler();
```

Also looking into your code I believe creating the thread would be unnecessary if you use postDelayed() method. It would update the text at certain intervals, usage as below:

```
 int j=0;
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        j++;
        timer.setText("Timer :"+j);
        Log.i("kbt", "inside for new");
      }
    }, 1000);
```